# copy value from a cell to cells in same row

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm kinda new into VBA and I need to copy the value from the cell "L3" to the cell B25. Then the value from "L3" should be refreshed and then copied to the C25 cell. I can't figure out how to change the value from the column to achieve my goal... I hope someone can help me with this.

Thank you in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

The cell `B25` can be addressed in VBA as `.Range("B25")` which is not very flexible. But it also can be addressed as `.Cells(25, 2)`. See [Worksheet.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx). With this you can replace the row `25` and the column `2` with a variable.

Example:

```
 With ActiveSheet
  For i = 2 To 5
   .Cells(25, i).Value = i
  Next
 End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I was actually trying to do it with .Range! I will try to figure out how to write my code on this style. :D